# Finding fully contained squares in a QPolygon?

Tags: c++, qt, polygon, intersection

I am looking for an approach to find a set of squares that are fully contained inside a QPolygon, which is not necessarily convex. My naive approach so far looks like this:

```
QRectF boundingRect(mShape->boundingRect());
for (int x = boundingRect.x() - 1; x < boundingRect.width(); x++)
{
    for (int y = boundingRect.y() - 1; y < boundingRect.height(); y++)
    {
        QRectF rect(x, y, 1, 1);
        QPolygonF cell(rect);
        QPolygonF intersection = mShape->polygon().intersected(cell);
        if (!intersection.empty())
        {
            // Cell is fully contained
        }
    }
}
```

When I visualise the result, it looks like this:

[image: Cells intersecting with the polygon are not left out]

This is almost what I want, except that the cells intersecting with the "outline" of the polygon shouldn't be there. Does anyone have a nice idea how I could construct a set of squares that are entirely "inside" the polygon?

Comment: Shouldn't `cell.subtracted(mShape->polygon());` return empty polygon if it is fully contained and not empty polygon if something left outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the larger polygon is convex (it is in your example), it should be sufficient to check that all four corners of your square are inside the larger polygon. Use the containsPoint method on the larger polygon.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I have forgotten to mention that the polygons are not necessarily convex. But thanks for the hint, for polygons that are convex this might be a nice speed up.

Comment: OK, then perhaps you could subtract the larger polygon from the square polygon. If the result is an empty polygon then the square was entirely inside the larger polygon. Checking the four corners before doing this would probably be a good idea too.